# Four lever door in harmugstahl

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I got through the door but then I accidentally walked off the ledge Back into the previous room now I'm stuck because I can't get back through please help. I'm playing the Xbox 360 version.

Comment: load previous save.

Comment: @kotekzot - wouldnt the 360 tag be useful to know that he cant use commands?

Comment: @ZeroStack you are correct, although he/she doesn't mention what he/she is playing skyrim on.

Comment: @Paralytic OP had 360 tagged in the original version.

Comment: @ZeroStack Since tags describe the problem and not just the general context, we don't use platform tags unless the problem is *about* the platform. (Eg., the 360 tag is good for Ring of Death questions or issues with reordering Skyrim DLC on a 360). Since the platform is just useful context here, it goes in the body, not the tags.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie oh okay, thanks for the clarification.  :)

Comment: @ZeroStack where he can or can not use commands is irrelevant, this is a question for everybody who might have that problem regardless of their platform.

Comment: @kotekzot We should, however, first and foremost answer the question for the asker. Other solutions for different platforms are a nice *addition*, but not *necessarily* helpful. (That said, if "load previous save" is the best solution in the end, it could - rather unlikely, however - be a X360-unique bug, so a PC solution may actually be *pointless*.)

Comment: @FEichinger that's really not how it works, or at least not how it worked until very recently. Remember the "too localized" close reason? If a problem is only applicable to one person, it is not worth our collective time.

Comment: @kotekzot I'm well aware of how it works. I'm merely objecting to you calling it entirely irrelevant. It's not as simple as that.